# Can I wrap the linux shutdown command to make additional checks?

Tags: linux

So we have a 3rd party process running intermittently which needs to shutdown gracefully. This process has a file present (lets call it /tmp/process1) when running. Is there anyway I can modify the standard linux shutdown process so that if this file is present the shutdown will be aborted (or delayed)?

Thanks

Comment: The system sends `SIGTERM` to all processes when it's shutting down. The process should have a handler for this signal that shuts it down gracefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a wrapper script named `shutdown`, and make sure it invokes the original `which shutdown` by its full path and that it's in a directory that overrides the directory of the original shutdown in `$PATH` (e.g., in `/usr/local/sbin`; see `echo $PATH`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the [Linux shutdown process](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#system-phases).

You will need to add the shutdown script for this 3rd party process to the appropriate run-levels.

This can also be used to start the process automatically on start.

Comment: He doesn't want to start the process automatically, he wants it to cancel the shutdown.

Comment: The desire appears to be a clean shutdown of  the 3rd party process.  By adding a shutdown script for the 3rd party process to the Shutdown run-level, he can get this without complicating the shutdown for the admin/operator.

This same approach can also be used to autostart the process when the system is booted.  However, you are correct and that is beyond the question asked.